# How to search for a keyword in entire website

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I want to know if a certain keyword exists in entire website.

How can I do it?

Quick googling suggested this way

> "Googling 101)
>
> .. just type your search terms, followed by  site:www.website.com

But I am not sure how to test if it returns positive or negative.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe your google was too quick? http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/277591-vbulletin-macro-search-webpage-text-string.html

Comment: @TimWilkinson No sir I was aware of that solution the difference is I want to search for entire site and not for a single webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it basically checks to see if there are any google search results by searching for a keyword or phrase on the site:

```
Sub Check_Website()

Dim ie As Object
Dim str As String, web As String, URL As String
Dim iResults As Integer

'Create IE object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set string to search for
str = "hello"
str = Replace(str, " ", "+")

'Set website to search in
web = "www.google.com"

'Create full URL
URL = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & str & "+site%3A" & web

'Navigate to URL
With ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate URL
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

'Count results on first page
iResults = ie.Document.getelementsbyclassname("g").Length

'Message box dependent on results
If iResults = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No matches were found."
Else
    MsgBox "Matches found."
End If

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Google uses the class name of "g" for there search results meaning there will be a maximum of 10 items in the "g" class for the particular search results page, if no results are shown there is no "g" class which means there are no items to be counted.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this also

```
Function FIND_IN_PAGE(strURL As String, strSearch As String)

Dim pos As Long
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = 1
ie.navigate strURL

Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = ie.document.DocumentElement

pos = InStr(1, doc.innerText, strSearch)

FIND_IN_PAGE = pos

ie.Quit

Set ie = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing

End Function
```

Calling like so

`FIND_IN_PAGE("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848321/how-to-search-for-a-keyword-in-entire-website","entire")`